# Yii framework: check if the user has filled the required profile fields

Tags: php, yii

I have some profile fields which are required, but not asked in the registration page.

How can I check, in the *themefolder\views\layout\tpl_navigation.php*, if they have completed their profile, to show an alert (*you have to complete your profile in order to...*) if they haven't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was easy:

```
$profile = Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user()->profile;
$validate =  $profile->validate();

if(!$validate) 
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error">Complete your profile...</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite that it's unclear, As a suggestion do like below:

I assume that you can get logged-in user id by:

```
$uid=Yii::app()->user->id;
```

And also, user's model is named `User`

Then, in your controller:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    //getting user id
    $uid=Yii::app()->user->id;
    //finding user 
    $user=User::model()->findByPk($uid);
    //checking if address or mobile is empty
    if(empty($user->address) || empty($user->mobile)){//and othe fields
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('PROFILE_IS_NOT_COMPLETED',TRUE);
    }
    parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Then  in your template:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('PROFILE_IS_NOT_COMPLETED') && Yii::app()->user->getFlash('PROFILE_IS_NOT_COMPLETED',FALSE)===TRUE) {
        echo CHtml::tag('span', array('style' => 'color:red'), "Please complete your profile"); //Just an example!
        //you absolutely need customization here
    }
```